# OwnerDrawLabelProvider highlights in 3D

Tags: swt, draw, jface

I am using JFace's OwnerDrawLabelProvider class to paint TableView's cells. I have several problems with it:

1. When I hover the mouse over the cell, it gets 3D highlighted, like if it was a tooltip with borders surrounding the cell, somewhat like it were floating over the actual cell.
2. I need to implement multiple tasks at once: I am implementing alternation of the row colors and at the same time I need to draw multi-line cell content which may contain both texts and drawings. The problem occurs with the text. If I don't use the SWT.DRAW_TRANSPARENT switch, the background of the text differs from the color of the row (which is alternated programatically); with the switch used I can achieve the transparency of the text, but then the letters aren't sharp, but rather they are getting some kind of reddish 'halo' surrounding them, which is ruining the look. I am using the antialiasing options of SWT GC for both the text and drawing, but no help.
   I would like to hear some suggestions or see examples. Thanks!

   It is happening on Windows 7.

Relevant code parts:

```
 @Override
```

protected void measure(Event event, Object element)
  {
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, column.getColumn().getWidth(), rowHeight);
    event.setBounds(new Rectangle(event.x, event.y, rectangle.width, rectangle.height));
  }

@Override
  abstract protected void paint(Event event, Object element);

@Override
  protected void erase(Event event, Object element)
  {

}

And in the implemented paint():

```
final Table table = viewer.getTable();
Point measure = new Point(0, 0);
PrioritiesForwardsDTO m = (PrioritiesForwardsDTO) element;
table.setRedraw(false);
int index = table.getTopIndex();
while (index < table.getItemCount())
{
  TableItem item = table.getItem(index);

  if (!abstractMultilineCellLabelProvider.isVisible(item))
  {
    return;
  }
  Color cx = null;
  boolean even = (index & 1) == 0;
  cx = getStripeColor(even);

  Rectangle bounds = event.getBounds();
  String firstline = (m.getSource() == null ? "" : m.getSource());
  String secondline = (m.getVendor() == null ? "" : m.getVendor());
  event.gc.setFont(boldFont);
  event.gc.setAntialias(SWT.ON);
  event.gc.setAdvanced(true);
  event.gc.setTextAntialias(SWT.ON);
  event.gc.setBackground(cx);
  event.gc.fillRectangle(bounds);
  event.gc.drawText(firstline, bounds.x + 1, bounds.y + 1, true);
  measure = event.gc.stringExtent(firstline);
  event.gc.setFont(smallBoldFont);
  event.gc.setAntialias(SWT.ON);
  event.gc.drawText(secondline, bounds.x + 1, bounds.y + measure.y + 4, true);
  item.setBackground(cx);
  table.setRedraw(true);
  index++;
```

}

And here is how it looks like:
[Image of the question](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1192316/highlight.png)

Comment: If this is on a Mac the 3D highlight is being done by OS X, I don't know of a way to stop it. For the rest of the question you probably need to show us code and pictures.

Comment: The `paint(Event event, Object element)` method wants you to draw the single row / cell for `element` **not** the entire table.

Comment: I understand it, and this implementation draws separate cells of a column, which is the OwnerDrawLabelProvider assigned to. But as you can see on the linked image, there's a floating highlight surrounding the drawn cell upon mouse hover (not visible when the mouse is out). The same stands also for the JFace's TreeViewer. If I use custom node display, where the items are drawn (because I have to, SWT is not about the fancy built-in components) when a node has focus and the viewer's composite is big enough to display the entire node, the highlight is off, in other cases it covers area off.